# Better way to strip text before specific character(s)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Not infrequently, I need to strip out all of the text up to and including a certain character. For example, in a list of legal cases in the form "Plaintiff v. defendant", I might want to strip off everything up to and including "v. " to get a list of defendants.

This is easily accomplished using a combination of the `FIND`, `RIGHT`, and `LEN` functions as follows (using `A1` as the cell where text is coming from):

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("text",A1)-1)
```

But has always struck me as somewhat clunky and error-prone (not to mention that I usually forget to subtract 1.  Is there a more elegant way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Excel in general is incredibly clunky =). Outside of VBA, I think that's pretty much the canonical way of doing what you outlined. What would pass your test for elegance?

Comment: @Joe.  Reasonable question.  I suppose using fewer functions would be desirable.  Having to use the `LEN` function particularly bothers me.  After posting, inspired by one of the answers below, I came up with an alternative of using the `REPLACE` function to replace text with nothing ("").  Uses one less function, but would now need to worry about length of search string: `REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("text",A1)+[length of text being searched for -1]),"")`  Not really an improvement in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of VBA is a legitimate strategy!  Hides those details and the burden of recalling them.  Also lets you use easier string functions (e.g., VBA's version of Mid() doesn't need a substring count - it will by default supply to the end of the string.) [Note 1]
The function you write becomes available for easy application in the Excel dropdown of functions of Excel.

Alt-F11 to enter VBA  (Alt-F11 to toggle back).
From the VBAProject for the current workbook, Insert > Module (right menu operation).  This will have the function easily accessible throughout your workbook.

Paste this:

```
Function RightOfToken(sSource As String, sToken As String) As String
Dim sTarget As String
Dim iPos As Integer

' Return the characters after the first occurence of sToken in sSource

iPos = InStr(sSource, sToken)
If iPos > 0 Then
    sTarget = Mid(sSource, Len(sToken) + iPos)
Else
    sTarget = ""
End If
RightOfToken = sTarget
End Function
```

Alt-F11 back.  In any cell, =RightofToken("ABC v. DEF","v.") will yield " DEF".
(You can use LTrim() in VBA to remove leading spaces or if it suits do TRIM in Excel)

[Note 1] If within VBA you should want the Excel version of a function, or a worksheet function specific to Excel, you can prefix it with Application.WorksheetFunction. .

Comment: Though VBA wasn't what I had in mind, I appreciate the answer and may use it.  I may well be missing something, but it seems from what I've looked at that a VBA function may be in a particular spreadsheet (in which case you'd need to recreate every time it is needed) or can live in the "personal" template, in which case it wouldn't be availbe if the worksheet were sent to someone else.  Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Find and Replace might work for you. It's the quickest. For your example "want to strip off everything up to and including "v. " to get a list of defendants", I would copy the info into a new column(s) then highlight just those columns. Then use Find and Replace or CTRL H.

In the find box, enter "*v. " or "**asterisk** v. ".  In the replace box, leave it empty. (The asterisk symbol* is a wild card so it will select everything before the V.) Click on ok to run and it should delete everything before and including the "v. ".

If you have everything you want to change highlighted first, you should be able to do all in one swoop very quickly.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I was intrigued by the findd and replace idea, even though it wouldn't work in many scenarios, but searching for wildcard before text string doesn't work in the way you describe.  (Indeed, it doesn't seem to work at all.)  Wildcard (*) can be at end of text string being searched, but not beginning.

Comment: That's weird. The wildcard works anywhere as long as the 'bookends' match what is being looked up. So if it doesn't work before the v, then the problem is the v., not the wildcard. I used it all the time- its faster than VBA or most formulas. So to me its an essential function to know.

Comment: [link](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/excel-wildcard/)

Comment: [https://www.deskbright.com/excel/excel-wildcard/]